# Is there a way to create multiple instances of same class within another class by @Autowired annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot - Is there a way to create multiple instances of same class within another class by @Autowired annotation?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

There is util class:

```
@Component
public class CICSUtil {
     .......
}
```

There is a service class:

```
@Service
public class Service {

@Autowired
private CICSUtil util1;

@Autowired
private CICSUtil util2;

}
```

In this service class, I want to create multiple instances of the Util class in a Spring boot project using autowiring approach.

Is there a way I can do that? Please help me out.
If not autowiring, let me know if there is an other cleaner way to do this.

Comment: you should change the scope properly (e.g. use prototype instead of the deafult singleton scope)

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Thanks!